# Как искать по значению поля класса при помощи find() в STL?

Tags: c++

Есть multiset из экземпляров класса. Можно ли произвести поиск элемента при помощи find() по значению одного из его полей? Как это сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если цель вашего поиска никак не может использовать сортированность `multiset`, т.е. обстоятельства действительно заставляют использовать именно линейный поиск, то ничего сложного тут нет. Все как обычно

```
std::multiset<SomeClass> m;

auto it = std::find_if(m.begin(), m.end(), 
  [](const SomeClass &s) { return s.some_field == some_value; });

if (it != m.end())
  ; // Нашлось
else
  ; // Не нашлось
```

А уж какое поле и с чем вы собираетесь сравнивать - это уже у вас надо спрашивать.

Comment: @Леонид Шахманаев: Исправил ошибку: разумеется для использования предиката нужен `std::find_if`, а не `std::find`.